# NLog not writing to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, nlog, azure-blob-storage

I'm new with Azure and I'm trying to get my first MVC Core 3.1 application on Azure to use NLog to write to an Azure Blob Storage. I believe I have it setup correctly but I'm not seeing anything in my Blob Storage.

I'm using the following articles to help.

[https://www.taithienbo.com/securely-log-to-blob-storage-using-nlog-with-connection-string-in-key-vault](https://www.taithienbo.com/securely-log-to-blob-storage-using-nlog-with-connection-string-in-key-vault/)
[https://ozaksut.com/custom-logging-with-nlog](https://ozaksut.com/custom-logging-with-nlog/)

When I look at my Blob Storage I don't see any files. I'm also assuming I have my Blob Storage setup correctly.

Here is a snippet of my proj file to show I have what should be the correct NLog packages.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.10">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.9.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.19.80" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.7.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="nlog.config">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Below is my NLog.config file. If I remove the `throwExceptions="true"` then the website will come up but no log files are created. If I leave the expections on then my website errors out and I see an error in the Azure logs that says `Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Settings must be of the form "name=value".` along with

```
at NLog.Targets.BlobStorageTarget.CloudBlobService.Connect(String connectionString, String serviceUri, String tenantIdentity, String resourceIdentity, IDictionary`2 blobMetadata, IDictionary`2 blobTags)
   at NLog.Targets.BlobStorageTarget.InitializeTarget()
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.NLog.Internal.ISupportsInitialize.Initialize(LoggingConfiguration configuration)
   at NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration.InitializeAll()
   at NLog.LogFactory.ReconfigExistingLoggers()
   at NLog.LogFactory.set_Configuration(LoggingConfiguration value)
   at NLog.LogFactory.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)
   at NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)
   at NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(String configFileName)
```

NLog.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>    
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" />
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <variable name="LogDirectory" value="D:\logs\MvcProjectName"/>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    
    <target xsi:type="File" 
      name="DefaultTarget" 
      fileName="${LogDirectory}\LogFile.log"
      layout="${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${callsite} | ${message}"
      archiveAboveSize="3145728"  
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveFileName = "${LogDirectory}/Archive/{#}.log"  
      archiveNumbering = "DateAndSequence"            
      archiveDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"  
      maxArchiveFiles = "50"            
    />

    <target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage"
        name="AzureBlob"
        blobName="Log-${shortdate}.log"
        container="epays-log"
        connectionString="https://myservername.blob.core.windows.net/epays-log"
        layout="${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${callsite} | ${message}">
    </target>

    <target name="ConsoleTarget"
      xsi:type="Console"
      layout="${longdate} ${logger:shortName=True} ${message} ${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=type,message,StackTrace,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=8:innerFormat=type,message,StackTrace,method}}"
    />
    
  </targets>  
  <rules>
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="DefaultTarget" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="AzureBlob" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="ConsoleTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

When I run the site locally, I'm able to get it to log to the local file structure using the "DefaultTarget" settings.

Comment: Looks like `connectionString` is not the connection-string but the `serviceUri`. Maybe remove `connectionString` and assign serviceUri instead: `serviceUri="https://myservername.blob.core.windows.net/epays-log"`

Comment: Thanks. Now that you've said that I think I have the URL which is not a connection string to the storage. I'm trying to look into where I get the connection string information from.

Comment: I didn't see where you use key vault, you could check if my answer helps or not. If it helps, would you mind accept it as the answer for others to refer? @Caverman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is seems your configuration file is correct but you didn't find where your connection string is.

Go to your storage account page, find **Access Key** under settings, copy the connection string to your `nlog.config` file.

[image]

Here is a sample on my side:

1. `nlog.config` file content:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          autoReload="true"
          internalLogLevel="info"
          internalLogFile="C:\temp\fallback-log.txt"
          throwConfigExceptions="true">

      <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
        <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" />
      </extensions>

      <targets async="true">
        <target
          xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage"
          name="azure"
          layout="${longdate:universalTime=true} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${logger}: ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
          connectionString="your-connection-string-goes-here"
          container="logs"
          blobName="${date:universalTime=true:format=yy-MM-dd}.log" />
      </targets>

      <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="azure" />
      </rules>

    </nlog>
   ```
2. The logs file generated by project:

[image]

Comment: I did have the URL to the storage vs a connection string. Researching connection strings last night which took me a while to find the screen shot you posted of the access keys. I tested it last night and it still didn't work for me but I'm thinking I still don't have the connection string correct. I just used the connection string directly from the Access Key section but reading some stuff last night I'm not sure if I'm supposed to put the URL to the storage container plus the connection string or I also saw a post that said I would need to change "&" to "&amp". Will try again tonight.

Comment: Sorry to hear you didn't solve this. Did you try the script I post? Just change the connection string to check if it is the string's fault.

Comment: I copied your NLog exactly with just changing the connection string and it worked. Now I just need to go back an retrofit my settings and see what happens. I'm sure I'll be referring back to this post and hope it helps someone else as well.

Comment: Technically another question and I'm trying to find the answer but in case this is a quick answer, my timestamps look to be in Zulu time. How can I format for the 6 hour offset to get me to US Central Standard Time? ${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}

Comment: @Caverman, could you please raise another question?