# Why NLog is unable to store logs in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, azure-blob-storage, nlog

I am working on a ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app "AzureLogging" that tests using NLog to write logs to Azure Blob Storage。 I am run into problem of unable to store log file in Azure blob storage, even though NLog works perfectly on local machine.

**Here are my setup and testing steps:**

1. The Blob storage has been setup in Azure portal and successfully tested all file operations: read, upload, download and delete.
2. In MVC App, loaded following packages (see code segment #1 below)
3. setup NLog.config file  including logging target in Azure (see code segment #2 below)
4. In program.cs file, specify using NLog as the logging provider (see code segment #3 below)
5. In order to make sure the Blob connection string and Storage access are working properly, I added actions to perform file operations in MVC app: list files, upload and delete.  They are working fine. (see code segment #4 below)

**PROBLEM Description**

- The Nlog is using the same Blob storage connection string, account name and access key as those actions in MVC app that perform file operations. When logging targe was changed to "azure", no log file was written to Blob storage.
- I also setup Nlog internal logging level as "Trace", and checked the internal log file. No obvious error was found there
- So far, I have not been able to identify what is the root cause.  I will appreciate any advice or troubleshooting suggestion.

**CODE #1: loaded packages**

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.18.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="5.2.5" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage" Version="4.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="5.3.5" />
```

**CODE #2 Nlog.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog-AspNetCore.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!--Console Target for hosting lifetime messages to improve Docker / Visual Studio startup detection -->
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="consoleTarget" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />

    <!-- File target for output app logs on local machine-->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="webLogTarget" fileName="c:\temp\logs\AzureLogging\AzureLogging_${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${callsite} ${message}"/>

    <!-- Azure blob storage target for output app logs to Azure storage -->
    <target xsi:type="AzureBlobStorage"  
        name="azure"
        connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https; AccountName=mdxstorage1; AccountKey=a/g/KptWTDUpY76/dZQYBkqmVB+CgjlgRw4LM7kb1pxMIlZkvg32x/ifbMtFh9uY9wRUoX6DxQSu+AStK//VEg==; EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"        
        containerName="mdxweblogs"
        blobName="AzureLogging_${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />

  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->

    <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.*" level="Warn" writeTo="consoleTarget" final="true" />
    
    <logger name="AzureLogging.*" minlevel ="Trace" writeTo="azure" />

  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**CODE #3: program.cs file**

```
using NLog;
using NLog.Web;

// Early init of NLog to allow startup and exception logging, before host is built
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Host.UseNLog();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**CODE #4: StorageController.cs**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using AzureLogging.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using NLog;

namespace AzureLogging.Controllers
{
    public class StorageController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<StorageController> _logger;
        private readonly string _stgConnString;
        private readonly string _stgContainer;

        public StorageController(ILogger<StorageController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _stgConnString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mdxstorage1;AccountKey=a/g/KptWTDUpY76/dZQYBkqmVB+CgjlgRw4LM7kb1pxMIlZkvg32x/ifbMtFh9uY9wRUoX6DxQSu+AStK//VEg==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

            _stgContainer = "mdxweblogs";
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("ListFiles");
        }

        public IActionResult ListFiles()
        {
            BlobStgViewModel viewModel = new();
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("List files in Azure Blob Storage");

                viewModel.Container = _stgContainer;    

                BlobContainerClient cntClient = new BlobContainerClient(_stgConnString, _stgContainer);

                foreach(BlobItem blob in cntClient.GetBlobs())
                {
                    viewModel.BlobList.Add(blob.Name);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error occurred when listing files in Azure Blob Storage");
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        public IActionResult UploadFile()
        { 
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile mediaFile)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Upload file {mediaFile.Name} to Azure Blob storage");

                if (mediaFile is not null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaFile.Name)))
                {
                    BlobContainerClient cntClient = new BlobContainerClient(_stgConnString, _stgContainer);

                    // Initialize BlobClient with the uploaded file name
                    var blobClient = cntClient.GetBlobClient(mediaFile.FileName);

                    // Get stream from uploaded file
                    using (var stream = mediaFile.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        // Upload the stream to Azure Blob storage asynchronously
                        await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("ListFiles");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error occurred when listing files in Azure Blob Storage");
            }
        }

        public IActionResult DeleteFile()
        {
            BlobStgViewModel viewModel = new();

            try
            {
                BlobContainerClient cntClient = new BlobContainerClient(_stgConnString, _stgContainer);

                foreach (var blobItem in cntClient.GetBlobs())
                {
                    viewModel.SelectionList.Add(new SelectListItem(blobItem.Name, blobItem.Name ));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error occurred when retrieving files from storage");
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DeleteFile(string selectedItem)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Delete file {selectedItem} from Azure Blob Storage");

                BlobContainerClient cntClient = new BlobContainerClient(_stgConnString, _stgContainer);
                BlobClient blobClient = cntClient.GetBlobClient(selectedItem);
                blobClient.Delete();
                return RedirectToAction("ListFiles");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Error occurred when delete file from storage");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe change from `ConnectionString` to `serviceUri="https://namehere.blob.core.windows.net"` when running in azure, which supports ManagedIndentity. See also https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md

Comment: I changed nlog config and replaced ConnectionString to ServiceUrl as "https://MDXlogging.azurewebsites.net" Tested the code locally and in Azure. Still not having any log file in AzureBlobStorage.  Need help with troubleshooting

Comment: Usually [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) is the place to look for issues. Maybe also verify that the place you are looking for "blobs" is the place where your are writing. Also a good idea to enable `throwConfigExceptions="true"`. Else contact Microsoft Support, since something wrong with Azure.

Comment: Could also be that your application exits (or crashes) without correctly flushing. Maybe add try-finally with `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` . Alternative change to `using var logFactory = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().LogFactory;`

Comment: In NLog internal log file, I found the first config error: Unable to load: NLog.extensions.AzureStorage.  I corrected this error by using NLog.extentions.AzureBlogStore.  2) The next error in internal log was "unknown property ServiceUrl".  I replaced it with original connection string. 3) now the internal log recorded error of "unknown property 'containerName'".  This property is used to setup logging target.  This is the property I found in NLog online doc. How should I correct this error?  Please help

Comment: I changed "containerName" propery to "container=...". The previous error was gone.  Now the error is related to the blob connection string. The error message is: "2023-11-09 10:39:04.1241 Error AzureBlobStorageTarget(Name=azure): Failed to create BlobClient with connectionString=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https; AccountName=mdxstorage1; AccountKey=a/g/KptWTDUpY76/dZQYBkqmVB+CgjlgRw4LM7kb1pxMIlZkvg32x/ifbMtFh9uY9wRUoX6DxQSu+AStK//VEg==; EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net. Exception: System.FormatException: No valid combination of account information found. I used same string in web code and works.

Comment: why the same connection string is not working in NLog target setting?

Comment: [Docs for NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md) does not mention `containerName` (But says `container`). And also doesn't mention `ServiceUrl` (But says `serviceUri`). Btw. careful with posting your ConnectionString with the `AccountKey`.

Comment: I changed target setting to use "container" and "ServiceUri". I am not sure what the URI should be. So I tried three different ones. 1) mdxstorage1.blob.core.windows.net.  It is listed in the Azure portal storage setting "Front door and CDN" section. The name of this setting is :original host name.  2) dexstorage1.z13.web.core.windows.net.  This is the alternate setting of "oringal host name . 3) mdxlogging.azurewebsites.net.  This is the web app default domain name.  All three got same error: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. What the URI format should be?

Comment: Thanks for remind me to be carefull about posting AcountKey.  Since this is my sandbox using developer free Azure service, it only has some dummy testing data and files

Comment: My initial comment showed [How to specify ServiceUri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70874174/193178). Alternative there is also  [How to find connectionstring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916189/193178). Again I'm not an expert in Azure Blob Storage, and how to configure authentication based on the azure-application-type

Comment: @bedrock please refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905065/nlog-not-writing-to-azure-blob-storage)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by replaced Nlog.extensions.AzureStorage package with NLog.extensions.AzureBlobStorage. The NLog.Config uses the Blob storage connection string and container name to specify the blob storage as logging